# PHPExcel Error on new server

Tags: phpexcel

Just transfered my installation to a new server.  I'm having trouble debugging this, to my knowledge all permissions are still identical or MORE open than my old server on the folders that the server creates/reads files in...

From all I can tell, it's just that a temp file can't be created somewhere, but I have no idea where...

> Warning: tempnam() [function.tempnam]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File() is not within the allowed path(s): (/:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/tmp) in /home/myacnt/public_html/users/internal/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5/Worksheet.php on line 346
>
> Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: Filename cannot be empty in /home/myacnt/public_html/users/internal/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5/Worksheet.php on line 347
>
> Warning: tempnam() [function.tempnam]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File() is not within the allowed path(s): (/:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/tmp) in /home/myacnt/public_html/users/internal/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5/Worksheet.php on line 346
>
> Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: Filename cannot be empty in /home/myacnt/public_html/users/internal/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5/Worksheet.php on line 347
>
> Warning: tempnam() [function.tempnam]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File() is not within the allowed path(s): (/:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/tmp) in /home/myacnt/public_html/users/internal/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5/Worksheet.php on line 346
>
> Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: Filename cannot be empty in /home/myacnt/public_html/users/internal/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5/Worksheet.php on line 347
>
> Warning: tempnam() [function.tempnam]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File() is not within the allowed path(s): (/:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/tmp) in /home/myacnt/public_html/users/internal/PHPExcel/Shared/OLE/OLE_File.php on line 95
>
> Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: Filename cannot be empty in /home/myacnt/public_html/users/internal/PHPExcel/Shared/OLE/OLE_File.php on line 96
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Can't create temporary file' in /home/myacnt/public_html/users/internal/PHPExcel/Shared/OLE/OLE_File.php:98 Stack trace: #0 /home/myacnt/public_html/users/internal/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5.php(190): PHPExcel_Shared_OLE_PPS_File->init() #1 /home/myacnt/public_html/users/functions/export.php(58): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5->save('/home/myacnt/...') #2 /home/myacnt/public_html/users/manager/functions/export.php(196): multiCSVToExcel(Array, '1305481112_Nick...') #3 /home/myacnt/public_html/users/manager/viewInvoice.php(13): exportInvoiceLog(Array) #4 {main} thrown in /home/myacnt/public_html/users/internal/PHPExcel/Shared/OLE/OLE_File.php on line 98

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're dealing with a restriction called [open_basedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) as indicated by your error message. You either have to check the value in `php.ini` (you can use `phpinfo()` to check this quickly) and put files in the directory indicated, modify the value, or simply disable it entirely. If you disable it, you'll need to make sure to do sanity checks on filenames, such as using [basename](https://www.php.net/basename) to remove potential "../../" traversal.

Comment: @onteria which value am i looking for in php.ini?  I set my directory that is 777 for temp files in `include` in php.ini which is along with `/user/lib/php:/user/local/lib/php:/tmp:/home/myacnt/uploaded_docs`  which is my 777 folder that this is trying to write to...

Comment: @Shackrock Check the link to `open_basedir` in my response

Comment: @onteria_ hmmm ok.  That makes sense.  So the next question is obviously, how do I overcome it for this ONE script?  I'm also kind of wondering why other scripts have no problem opening it, but this class does??

Comment: @Shackrock Unfortunately I don't know enough about the codebase to answer why other scripts have it working. You should post the code you're using to call this class, and output the filename you're passing into it and verify the location of the file is correct.

Comment: @onteria_  take a look at this:  `If your server is complete run by yourself and with no clients on then you can turn it off in php.ini.

However if you are using your server for lots of clients I would only turn it off for your OWN sites (as it's a security setting). `  Would you agree?  This server is a VPS, all mine, w/ root access...

Comment: @onteria_ by the way, I disabled it on my domain and had no problems, so it's definitely that!

Answer (score 2):

This fix worked for me:

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/workitem/17840

The changes must be applied to Shared/File.php